# Multi-hot labels encoding

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to Tensorflow. I have a image dataset with several labels for one image. As far as I understand, I need to use `tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy()`. I tried to apply `tf.one_hot` to labels but when I try to pass them into loss function I get error, shapes incompatible. How can I fix this?

Comment: post the error message

Comment: Show an example of code illustrating your problem. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for inspiration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right about `tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy`. All you need to do is wrap `tf.one_hot` with `tf.reduce_max` to reduce dimensionality like this.

```
tf.reduce_max(tf.one_hot(labels, num_classes, dtype=tf.int32), axis=0)
```

That should return tensor of shape `(num_classes,)`, exactly what is needed for your loss function.